# RMAN online full backup without archivelogs

Tags: oracle11g, rman, symantec, sysdba

I need to take oracle database full backup (online) which is in archivelog mode. My current archive redo log partition space is very less, so i backup and delete archived redo log files then and there to manage the space. My question if i take rman full online backup without archive redo logs using command "backup incremental level 0 database" will it be consistent or not while restoring?

Answer (score 0):

Backing up a running Oracle Database in ARCHIVELOG mode will create an inconsistent (hot) backup. You can verify this by running rman> list backup; (checking SCN of datafile, controlfile, spfile). With inconsistent backup - when restoring DB'll be inconsistent state and require some archive(s) to recover to an specific SCN.